# API on dockerized application not reachable from host

Tags: python-3.x, api, docker, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Docker Desktop (Version 2.0.0.0-win81 (29211)) on a Windows 10 64bit machine. I also activated WSL and intstalled and configured Ubuntu 18.04.1 following this guide: [Docker on Windows and WSL](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work).

Now closing in on my issue: I am running and working with docker containers that i use out of the box, a mongodb and a neo4j db. They are fine.

I recently decided to dockerize my own Python3.6 application using Flask. This application has an API and shall be deployed on a cloud server in the near future.

If i am running the application locally, i can interact with the api via postman (GET, POST) and everything works as good/bad as intended.

So i built the image with the ports exposed, deployed the docker container while publishing the ports and started it (code given below), looks good:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
fba51f89f31a        m002_production:latest   "python communicatio…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5003->5003/tcp             M002_gi
f36cd69cf5ce        mongo:4.1.5              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                   M002_testmongo
ae8d610bbcd8        neo4j:3.0                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   M002_testneo4j
```

Then i check if the application started properly with 'docker logs M002_gi':

```
Path given:  /config/
 * Serving Flask app "M002" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

It did start as expected. However reaching the API does not work. What i know right now:

- The port bindings and published ports seem fine.
- All containers have the same network settings according to docker inspect, i even ran a diff on the whole docker inspect in order to find a clue to the solution - there is no clue.
- If i enter the docker containers via docker exec -it ... and check all network functions using curl: everything works as expected.
- The other two containers (neo4j and mongodb) are reachable from outside a.k.a. the host pc.
- My own python application container is not.

Hence i am for sure missing something but i can't figure out what it is.
The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
MAINTAINER default "addanaddress@here.com"
# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /M002/requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update build-base
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
EXPOSE 5003/tcp
# holds externally mounted volumes
VOLUME ["/M002/data", "/M002/config"]
WORKDIR /M002
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /M002
# this is the main executable
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
# this is the default argument for the executable
CMD [ "communication_handler.py", "/config/" ]
```

My docker build command:

```
docker build -t m002_production:latest .
```

My docker run command:

```
docker run --name M002_test -p 5000:5000 -p 5003:5003 -v /c/Users/MyName/MyConfig:/M002/config -v /c/Users/MyName/MyConfig:/config --rm -d m002_production:latest
```

My query result when i run the api query against the local version (without docker on port 5001): [Successful query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtCB6.png)
My query result when i run it against the dockerized version (port 5000 exposed and published): [Failed query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0nsn.png)

When i curl from Hyper:

```
curl localhost:5000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

What i expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

What i tried so far (in addition to all the things i found on the internet):

- Calling FLASK run with other IPs, including 0.0.0.0, localhost, and
  the IPs compatible with the docker system and various other ports.
- Assigning different docker bridge networks to the containers (default, and MProject). I made sure the containers assignement to the networks is correct.

My docker network ls:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
a41825cf65ca        MProject            bridge              local
60aae249fa11        bridge              bridge              local
3f5cb1334815        host                host                local
b6746f907725        none                null                local
```

Summary of my findings so far:

- curl@host -> mongodb@docker : works
- curl@host -> neo4j@docker: works
- postman@host -> mongodb@docker : works
- postman@host -> neo4j@docker : works
- mypythonapplication@host (not dockerized) -> mongodb@docker : works
- mypythonapplication@host (not dockerized) -> neo4j@docker :  works
- curl/postman@host -> mypythonapplication@host (not dockerized) : works

  if i log in with: docker exec mypythonapplication -it sh,  then use
  curl or ping or whatever i get exactly the responses i expect, so:
- mypythonapplication@docker -> mongodb@docker : works
- mypythonapplication@docker -> neo4j@docker : works
- curl@host -> mypythonapplication@docker : does NOT work
- postman@host -> mypythonapplication@docker: does NOT work

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: How do you test the neo4j and mongo? Which host name do you use for these containers? Also `localhost`?

Comment: Yes i also use localhost for mongodb and neo4j. I can query those services using curl from Ubuntu, or query from Postman, or query from within the alpine container where my dockerized python application runs, as well as using the browser interface for neo4j. if i run my python application without docker i can interact from there with both docker containers. No problem at all.

Comment: Have you tried running it with debug mode on? I expect it is more a case of your python container internally going wrong somewhere (dependency, connection with other container, anything), since you get an `empty reply` instead of a connection refused or similar which would happen if it was not reachable at the specified host + port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're problem is most likely caused by flask using the "wrong" IP:
`Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Default for flask is to listen on localhost only, in this case that would be localhost *within* the container and not localhost of the docker host.

Try starting flask like this instead:
`flask.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`